# Joining together 2 SQL queries to obtain weekday average and weekend average results in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries that work fine separately: one query extracts average sales of pens & pencils from a sales table for each salesperson for WEEKDAYS for each month of a year and the other query extracts average sales of pencils and pens from the same sales table for each salesperson for WEEKENDS for each month of a year. I can't figure out how to join the two queries together so that average sales for pencils and pens for weekends AND weekdays appear in the same result set.
My two separate working queries are:

++++++++++++++FIRST QUERY+++++++++++++++++

```
SELECT salesperson, 
       Avg([pencil_sales]) [pencil_salesAV], 
       Avg([pen_sales]) [pen_salesAV], 
       Month(the_date) Month,
       Year(the_date) Year
FROM regionalsales 
WHERE DATEPART(w,[the_date]) NOT IN (1,7)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((Month(the_date), Year(the_date), salesperson), (salesperson));
```

+++++++++++++++++SECONDQUERY++++++++++++++++

```
SELECT salesperson, 
       Avg([pencil_sales]) [pencil_salesAV],
       Avg([pen_sales]) [pen_salesAV],
       Month(the_date) Month,
       Year(the_date) Year
FROM regionalsales 
WHERE DATEPART(w,[the_date]) NOT IN (2,3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((Month(the_date), Year(the_date), salesperson), (salesperson));
```

++++++++++++++++++++
I would appreciate advice on how to join these two queries into one result set. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT salesperson, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) NOT IN (1, 7) THEN  [pencil_sales] END)) as pencil_salesAV_weekday, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) NOT IN (1, 7) THEN [pen_sales] END) as pen_salesAV_weekday, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) IN (1, 7) THEN  [pencil_sales] END)) as pencil_salesAV_weekend, 
       Avg(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) IN (1, 7) THEN [pen_sales] END) as pen_salesAV_weekend, 
       Month(the_date) as Month,
       Year(the_date) as Year
FROM regionalsales 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((Month(the_date), Year(the_date), salesperson), (salesperson));
```

Comment: That's great. It's the first time I have used CASE in sql queries and it advances my knowledge in that area. Thanks.

Comment: You need to be aware of **DATEFIRST** for this solution to -always- work as expected. Sometimes 1 or 7 may not be the days you expect them to be.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx

Comment: @Used_By_Already . . . Note:  You comment is correct but is assumed by the OP in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Just treat day of week as a field to group the data:

```
SELECT
  salesperson, 
  day_of_week,
  month,
  year,
  Avg([pencil_sales]) [pencil_salesAV], 
  Avg([pen_sales]) [pen_salesAV]
FROM (
  SELECT 
    salesperson,
    pencil_sales,
    pen_sales,
    IF(DATEPART(w,[the_date]) IN (1,7), 'weekend', 'weekday') AS day_of_week,
    Month(the_date) AS month,
    Year(the_date) AS year
  FROM regionalsales
) AS sales
GROUP BY salesperson, day_of_week, month, year
GROUPING SETS(salesperson, (salesperson, day_of_week), (salesperson, day_of_week, month, year));
```

If the dialect of sql you use doesn't have `IF`, you can always use `CASE`.

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(w,[the_date]) IN (1,7) THEN 'weekend' ELSE 'weekday' AS day_of_week
```

Comment: I would like to try this to compare with the CASE sql query left by Gordon Linoff, but I am getting the following errors relating to the IF statement line: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line number 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line number 13
Incorrect syntax near ','.I would very much like to get this working as an alternative to CASE if you can assist?

Comment: @MikeM what dialect of sql are you using?

Comment: Hi Huang. I am using MSSQL. Your suggestion of using CASE works well, but in the MSSQL dialect I am using I had to add a comma between GROUP BY line and GROUPING SETS line. I experimented with the IF suggestion and found using IIF instead of IF in my sql dialect makes this line work. The resulting dataset is slightly different from Gordon Linoff's suggestion but I have a need for both and it is useful for me to know how to do this. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @MikeM You're welcome. A upvote will be appreciated :D